# Java conditional statement confusion

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

Testing out a simple while loop but I'm confused, if `bottle` is `1`,name is `"bottle"`.

But even when `bottle` is greater that `1`, it still prints `"bottle"` and not `"bottles"`

```
public class ex {
  public static void main(String[] arg) {
    int bottle = 0;
    String name = "bottles";
    while (bottle < 100) {
      if (bottle == 1) {
        name = "bottle";
      }
      System.out.println(bottle + " " + name);
      ++bottle;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once `bottle` is set to 1, name will always be `"bottle"` and not `"bottles"` because you never change it back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `name` keeps the value in singular as is never reasigned with the **"bottles"** value. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
  int bottle = 0;
  String name = "bottles";
  while( bottle < 100) {
    name = "bottles"
    if(bottle == 1) {
      name = "bottle";
    }
    System.out.println(bottle + " " + name);
    ++bottle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you set name = "bottle"; then name will always be "bottle" unless you change it back. After the if statement add:

```
else {
    name = "bottles";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (bottle == 1) {
    name = "bottle";
  }else{
    name = "bottles";
  }
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, please explain how it works and why it should be the selected answer. The goal is to educate, not just answer the immediate question.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. And afterall I don't want to use **else** since it's a single condition with only one possible output.      Thanks to SCouto for the insight